# Fabric Connect through gateway using Key from Gateway

Tags: ssh, fabric, paramiko

I need to connect to an EC2 instance via a gateway machine.  The key file is stored on the gateway machine.  The following ssh command connects me:

```
ssh -t gateway ssh ec2
```

However, in my fabfile I have the following set:

```
env.hosts = ['ec2.<snip>.compute.amazonaws.com']
env.gateway = 'gateway'
```

But it prompts me for a password when connecting to ec2.

The [troubleshooting guide](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/troubleshooting.html) says to execute the command with 'ssh -t'.  When I do that, it works:

```
local> ssh -t gateway ssh ec2.compute.amazonaws.com /bin/bash -l -c "uname -a"
Linux
Connection to gateway closed.
```

Here is the fabric and paramiko debugging info:

```
local> fab --show=debug uname
Using fabfile '/home/matt/.../fabfile.py'
Commands to run: uname
Parallel tasks now using pool size of 1
[ec2-.compute.amazonaws.com] Executing task 'uname'
[ec2-.compute.amazonaws.com] run: /bin/bash -l -c "uname -a"
Creating new gateway connection to 'gateway'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xb6e50dd0L
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.3)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:[u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa', u'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:[u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128', u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc', u'arcfour', u'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:[u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128', u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc', u'arcfour', u'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:[u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-sha1', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:[u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-sha1', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:using kex diffie-hellman-group14-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key e35b78f<snip>80bff41ce73484
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) successful!
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xb6eacf10L
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.2)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:[u'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa', u'ssh-dss', u'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256'] client encrypt:[u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc', u'arcfour', u'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] server encrypt:[u'aes128-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes256-ctr', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128', u'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes256-gcm@openssh.com', u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc', u'arcfour', u'rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se'] client mac:[u'hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-sha1', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'umac-128@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:[u'hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-64-etm@openssh.com', u'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com', u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-sha1', u'umac-64@openssh.com', u'umac-128@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] server compress:[u'none', u'zlib@openssh.com'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:using kex diffie-hellman-group14-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-rsa host key for ec2-.compute.amazonaws.com: 4fb53<snip>8579c5f
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key e35b78f1<snip>484
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key e35b78<snip>484 in /home/matt/.ssh/id_rsa
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) failed.
[ec2-.compute.amazonaws.com] Login password for 'user':
```

It looks like paramiko is trying to use the key files from my local machine.  How do I get fabric to use the key file from the gateway machine?

Comment: You want to run fabric from your host machine to make changes on a target machine which is bridged by an intermediate machine? Wouldnt it be easier to keep a separate fabric file on the intermediate machine and then then run fabric command on this machine by your host?

Comment: The intermediate machine doesn't have python and would probably be an issue to install due to our setup in the organization.

Answer (score 0):

Test if you can connect to your EC2 instance using your gateway as a [JumpHost](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Passing_Through_One_or_More_Gateways_Using_ProxyJump):

```
 ssh -J gateway:22 ec2:
```

If that works you then could configure your `~/.ssh/config` with something like:

```
Host ec2
    HostName X.X.X.X 
    ProxyJump user@gateway:22
    User matt
```

And then in `fabric` is as host `ec2` in case you have multiple instances you could have something like:

```
Host X.X.X.*
    ProxyJump user@gateway:22
```

In this case, when trying to ssh to any IP (`X.X.X.*`) it will use the `JumpHost`